# Can you use nested Repeating Content Controls with the Populate a Microsoft Word template action?

Tags: ms-word, workflow, azure-logic-apps, cpu-word, word-template

Basically what I am trying to accomplish is to have a table which has a section for each Division and within that section have subsections for each Company within that Division. This is as close as I have gotten (with DivisionTable and CompanyTable both being repeating content controls):

[image]

After populating the template from a workflow the Divisions are working fine (its repeating three times w/ the correct info) but in the Company Table it just shows [obj] where it should be the Company Name. It also looks like there may be two new unnamed tags placed here after its generated but I'm not sure.

[image]

In the Populate a Word Template action inside the DivsionTable tag I am putting an array:

[image]

This is what the first object in the array looks like:

```
 {
   "CompanyTable": [
     {
         "CompanyName": "Company Name Goes Here"
     }
   ],
   "DivisionDesc": "Finishes",
   "DivisionNo": "09"
 }
```

Is what I am trying to do even possible? I looked at some other posts but I never saw a clear answer.

If it is possible then what exactly am I doing wrong? If it is not possible do you have any suggestions on how to accomplish this another way?

Comment: How do you map the fields to the content controls? In general that should work - I have done that - using plain xml-files ..

Comment: @Ike I added a screenshot to it in my post. Basically the workflow action will show you the content control and you just say what you want to go there.

Comment: @Ike Also, do you have any links/resources about doing something like this using xml files? I would greatly appreciate it if you do!

Comment: Maybe I was on the wrong way: I am doing this in VBA ... so presumably my solution won't help you.